Acer monitor brightness up button issue
I have an older Acer monitor that I got used from a friend and today while I was using it a little window kept popping up with the brightness level and it took me a minute to figure out that the button that turns the brightness up was acting like it was being pressed but it was not. The button itself is not the issue, it is not stuck or damaged in any way and I can press other buttons and it responds to the other buttons but immediately goes back to acting like I've hit the brightness up button. Is there a way I can manually disable that button? I use it with a PS4 and not a computer so the only controls that I have are the actual buttons on the monitor. I removed the button itself to see if that would fix the issue and it did not. Is there something that I can do at home to fix it without having to go to a ton of trouble?

what is a ton of trouble?

Money, I don't have that.

Does the up button work normally when you do press it? If so, the switch behind the button MAY be OK, but you need to actually open the monitor physically in order to inspect the switch and its connections. This is a physical repair, even to just disable the button. As such, it is going to be rather too complex for us to do a good job helping you here. If you're not competent repairing electronic hardware, you'll probably save money taking the screen to a repair shop. That, or they'll be able to tell you that you'll be better off buying a different screen.
